# How to get this layout as shown in image

Tags: android, android-layout

`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/top_red_bar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/job_bar" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/jobseekers" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" >
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Job Seekers"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView5"
    android:src="@drawable/employer" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Code given above was done to create similar layout that of mentioned in image.But Imageview is not touching top of the screen. What parameter should I apply to imageview so that it is placed at the top of screen.
And also width of image is not fitting the screen even after giving width parameter as fill_parent.could anyone help in setting it right.

Comment: try setting android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: The values you apply to your Imageview also depend on the layout wrapper you use... Which one do you use?

Comment: @ChrisConway NO... it depends on **padding**. He said: `the image doesn't touch the borders`. What has this to do with the container?

Comment: OK, apart that `fill_parent` is deprecated since API level 8 (use `match_parent`, instead), you have to chech out the theme you are using. Search in the `values` folders for your dimens (or you can disable that in your styles or in themes) xml files. There should be a default dimension for your padding - set it to 0dp

Comment: @DerGolem "Imageview is not touching top of the screen" and "What parameter should I apply to imageview so that it is placed at the top of screen"- the container handles the alignment of its child parents with different properties. Anyway - just wanted to see some code to help, no need to get rude.

Comment: @ChrisConway ... rude? I just asked. because he's asking why the ImageView has some padding (obviously, if it doesn't reach the top and the width). This is really independent of the parent. A RelativeLayout has the same chances (and even more) to be "touched" by the contained Views as a LinearLayout or any other container. Is this rude?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the following  :

[Padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0AH0.png)

Remove the android:padding attributes set for your layout by default by Eclipse.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```